# Facebook API - login with JSSDK use php sdk in back end

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working on this web application that I use the FB JSSDK to log the user in, on some other page in the back end I want to do some functions like:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

For this first I need to do this:

```
$config = array(
          'appId' => 'xxx',
          'secret' => 'xxx',
          'cookie' => true,
          'fileUpload' => false, 
          'allowSignedRequest' => false,
      );

      $facebook = new Facebook($config);


      return $facebook;
```

I've already logged in once with JSSDK, is the a way to read the cookie or somehow use the php functions without logging again?

Comment: What is your original task? Why do you want to read fb authentication cookie?

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook->getMetadataCookie()
```

would return all the contents of authentication cookie.

But you better explain what do you need it for.

References:

- https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L1427

Comment: So on the home page there is the JS login button. Nothing happens here so I don't need to anything in the backend. But in the second page I need to read user information such as name and image. For that I need to use $facebook and without the login function I won't have $facebook.

Comment: @Ali.B: okay. So? Does the cookie disappear when user goes to the second page?